# React Links passing variables across pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following link setup on my `/home` page in react. Once the link is pressed I want to pass the variable `stockRow` to the `/quotes` page.

```
<Link to = "/quotes" params={{ testvalue: stockRow }} >
```

On my `/quotes` page I was wondering how to grab that variable?

```
export default function Quotes() {

let variable = //Grab stockRow

  return (

  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated the answer with more research:**

Below are the different approaches to pass data using `Link`

**1st approach:**

- pass the params as a query. In this case, it will appear as url in the query param.

```js
<Link to={{pathname: `quotes`, search: `?testvalue=${stockRow}`}} />
```

- receive it in the component like this:

```js
const search = props.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
const testvalue = params.get('testvalue');
console.log(testvalue);
```

- Note: also use [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to parse the query
- advantage of 1st approach is that you share the url with others and the data persists on refresh. You can also pass arrays/objects by serialising it

**2nd approach:**

- use route param
- configure your route like this

```js
<Route path="/quote/:testvalue" component={Quotes} />
```

```js
<Link to=`/quotes/${stockRow}`>Go To Quotes Page</Link>
```

- receive it in the component like this:

```js
export default function Quotes(props) {

let variable = props.match.params.testvalue

  return (

  ); 
}
```

- advantage of 2nd approach is that you share the url with others and the data persists on page refresh. However you can only use minimal types of data structure like string and numbers.

**3rd approach:**

- pass the data in the `to` prop of `Link` as a `state` value

```js
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/quotes',
      state: { testvalue: stockRow }
    }}> My Link </Link>
```

- receive it in the component like this:

```js
export default function Quotes(props) {

let variable = props.location.state && props.location.state.testvalue

  return (

  ); 
}
```

- advantage of this is that you can pass any kind of data to state. However on page refresh, data won't persist and you need to handle this case in your component.

Comment: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined' is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your passed value through router **params**

```
export default function Quotes({match}) {

 const { testvalue } = match.params;
 console.log(testvalue);

  return (

  ); 
}
```